# Allowing user input once per minute

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I have trouble getting this to work.

The thing is that a user is only allowed to create a comment once per minute. As simple as that....

```
$checkLastComment = Comment::where('user_id', '=', 1)
        ->where('created_at', '<', 'CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE')->count();
```

Comment: Do you get a error? Please provide us with more information. Perhaps you've to make it a ```whereRaw('created_at < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE')``` because laravel probably add quotes so mysql doesn't execute that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use here rather:

```
$checkLastComment = Comment::where('user_id', '=', $id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)')->first();

if ($checkLastComment) {
  // user not allowed to add new comment
}
```

Answer (score -1):

3 issues in your code:

1. You need greater than `>`, not less than `<` operator
2. You need raw condition
3. You can't use `curdate()` since it's time part is `00:00:00` always.

So here's what you want:

```
$notAllowedToComment = Comment::where('user_id', '=', 1)
    ->where('created_at', '>', DB::raw('now() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE'))->count();
```